# Write function mult3() that takes as input a list of integers and prints only the multiples of 3, one per line

Tags: python

I need to write a function which does the following:
1. Takes a list as input.
2. Print only multiples of 3, one per line.

I figured it out task 1, but I am stuck on 2 on the one per line part.

```
def mult3(lst):
    for num in lst:
        if num % 3 == 0:
            print(num, end=' ')
        print()
```

I know the problem is in the last print() function, in the current code it still prints a new line but just leaves it empty. I think this happens because of the fact that:

```
    for num in lst:
        if num % 3 == 0:  
        print()
```

Will print a line even if the number is not a multiple of 3. This makes sense but I cant figured out how to only print a line when if num % 3 == 0: is true

Comment: Why do you set `end=' '` if they should be on separate lines?

Comment: What @jonrsharpe meant to say was instead of `print(num. emd=' ')`, use `print(num)`. This would go one line down automatically each time you call `print`

Comment: Thanks guys. I see my mistake I should not have used the end argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply print new line character within the if statement as endline string:

```
def mult3(lst):
    for num in lst:
        if num % 3 == 0:
            print(num, end='\n')
```

Comment: Yep, just don’t pass anything to the `end` argument.

Comment: Yupp but its for clarification purposes. As he used endline and and a separate print for line insertion